# How to use alpha channel with emission?

Tags: lighting, unreal-4, unreal, materials, glow

I am trying to assemble scene assets and one asset needs an emission material where only the white part emits light:

[image: white part of diamond pattern should emit light]

I set up a texture with a simple (air-quotes) "mask" for the window...

[image: material with not much going on yet]

...and tried to make only the white part emit light. This attempt blew up the entire material though (verified by checking model, adjusting intensity). I also tried plugging in the base texture directly but when I turned up the intensity, it looked like the black frame became a deeper black as well, which is not what I want.

[image: nope...]

Changing the intensity with just the white input and scalar multiplier does not reveal the black metal portion of the diamond pattern. **How can I update this graph so that only the white part glows?**

I want to use the texture to light the scene but may settle for filler lights, since it could be overkill. Here is the original scene I put together in Blender. The camera will be fixed like this. Note also that there are 9 other windows that emit light in this scene but are made invisible:

[image]

Thank you to everyone who takes an interest in helping me solve this problem, your time is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Alpha channel on that texture, or some other channel to use as a mask - you can fake Alpha for emission by just multiplying the BaseColor (RGB) with your Alpha or Mask. multiplication and then just plug it into the emissive color on the material